# jQuery ajax fail handler triggered on cross domain request/response

Tags: jquery

The below "addReqeust" does succeed in the sense that the Java servlet gets the request and successfully persists the data (using GAE). But the "fail handler" is triggered.
The origin of the request is my GAE local host. The url is on Google's App Engine server. Curious why this happens. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
    var addRequest = $.ajax({
    context: this, 
    url: myServlet,
    type: "POST",
    data: joText,
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true // added this to see if it prevents fail, it does not.
    });


 addRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
     alert("Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your servlet returns response code not equals to 200? You can check it with firebug and firefox. It shows in console request/response results.